# openpyxl を使って Excel ファイルに列を追加しデータを追記したい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

Python3で`openpyxl`を使ってExcelのデータを読み込みTwitterへ検索しています。
各国を検索したらExcelのD列に`処理済み`の結果を記載したいですが、
上手く処理できないです。

自分の力不足が大きいのですが、調べていてイマイチ記述方法がわかりません。
申し訳ないのですが、皆さんのお知恵をお借りできないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

**Excel Data**

| 国 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 |
| アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 |
| フランス | パリ | 13 |
| 日本 | 東京 | 26 |
| 日本 | 沖縄 | 10 |
| 日本 | 京都 | 11 |

**実現したいエクセルの結果　RESULT Excel Data**
例：ループで完了している場合、
下記のように`処理済み` のフラグをつけたいです。
元々はエクセルにはヘッダーがないですのでD列からつけたいです。

| 国 | 都市 | 地域 | フラグ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 | 処理済み |
| アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 |  |
| フランス | パリ | 13 | 処理済み |
| 日本 | 東京 | 26 | 処理済み |
| 日本 | 沖縄 | 14 |  |
| 日本 | 京都 | 11 |  |

**Code**

```
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
# シートのロード
ws = v_wb.worksheets[0]

# convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
print(df)


# generate search words
lst = (
  df.groupby(1, as_index=False)[2]
    .agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    .apply(lambda x: [x[1]] + x[2], axis=1)

    .tolist()
)
print(lst)

URL = "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en"

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

for i, query in enumerate(lst):
    # Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
    if i > 0:
      driver.execute_script('window.open()')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    driver.get(URL)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # country
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(query[0])

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # 都市1つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 1:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
      city2.send_keys(query[1])

    # 都市2つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 2:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
      city2.send_keys(query[2])

    # 都市3つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 3:
      city3 = driver.find_element_by_name("noneOfTheseWords")
      city3.send_keys(query[3])
      
    # 処理済みのでデータをD列へ入力
    v_ws['D'+str(i+1)].value = str("処理済み")      

# EXCEL保存  
v_wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

**現在の結果**
フランスまでしか処理済み書き込みされないです。

| 国 | 都市 | 地域 | フラグ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 | 処理済み |
| アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 | 処理済み |
| フランス | パリ | 13 | 処理済み |
| 日本 | 東京 | 26 |  |
| 日本 | 沖縄 | 14 |  |
| 日本 | 京都 | 11 |  |

Comment: `i` が `0` の場合、`D0` となってエラーになっています。エラーメッセージにある通り、行番号は `1` から始まるので、`'D'+str(i+1)` とする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`'D'+str(i+1)`でExcelへ書き込みできましたが、ただ上記のように行うと実際に日本までループしていますが、`処理済み`はフランスまでしか行かないんです。３回までループしているからだと思いますが、各国でループしてもExcelへ書き込み可能でしょうか。

Comment: 度々すいません、各国（重複）でループしもExcelへ書きできそうですが、下記の方法でIFを使うと`アメリカ`まで処理済みとしか記載されないです。`query[0]`を変える必要ありますでしょうか。もしわかれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
`# Excelへ検索した結果をD列へ書き込み
    v_ws['D'+str(i+1)].value = str("処理済み")

    if v_ws['A'+str(i+1)].value  == query[0]:
     v_wb.save("test.xlsx")`

Comment: Excel データではなく、pandas dataframe(`df`)を更新する方がよいかと思います。 そして for loop での処理が完了した後、`df` の内容を Excel 形式でファイルに保存する様にします。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。上記の方法試してみます

Comment: @metropolisさん　下記の方法でも行いましたが同じように行とズレ`処理済み`と表示されます、すいませんdataframeの部分はどのように変更すればよろしいですか。何回も調べとイマイチ分からないです。いつもすいません。
`# 都市1つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 1:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
      city2.send_keys(query[1])
      v_ws[list+str(i+1)].value = str("処理済み")`

Comment: 少しずつ理解しました。教えてもらった方法で追加の質問解決できました。本当にいつもありがとうございます。いつか@metropolisさんのようになりたいです。`# 処理済みのでデータをD列へ入力
    df.loc[(df[1] == query[0]), 'フラグ'] = "処理済み"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
# シートのロード
ws = v_wb.worksheets[0]

# convert to pandas dataframe
data = ws.values
columns = next(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

# generate search words
lst = (
  df.groupby('国', as_index=False)['都市']
    .agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    .apply(lambda x: [x['国']] + x['都市'], axis=1)
    .tolist()
)
print(lst)
df['フラグ'] = ''

URL = "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en"

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

for i, query in enumerate(lst):
    # Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
    if i > 0:
      driver.execute_script('window.open()')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    driver.get(URL)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # country
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(query[0])

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # 都市1つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 1:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
      city2.send_keys(query[1])

    # 都市2つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 2:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
      city2.send_keys(query[2])

    # 都市3つ以上がある場合、c列を入力
    if len(query) > 3:
      city3 = driver.find_element_by_name("noneOfTheseWords")
      city3.send_keys(query[3])

    # 処理済みのでデータをD列へ入力
    df.loc[(df['国'] == query[0]).idxmax(), 'フラグ'] = "処理済み"

    pyautogui.press(['enter'])

# EXCEL保存  
df.to_excel("test2.xlsx", index=False)
```

**test2.xlsx**

| 国 | 都市 | 地域数 | フラグ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 | 処理済み |
| アメリカ | フロリダ | 22 |  |
| フランス | パリ | 13 | 処理済み |
| 日本 | 東京 | 26 | 処理済み |
| 日本 | 沖縄 | 10 |  |
| 日本 | 京都 | 11 |  |

Comment: @metropolisさん
回答ありがとうございます。度々、すいません。ちなみに全てのD列のフラグに処理済みと記載したい場合、どのように変更すればよいでしょうか。例：`アメリカ フロリダ`の都市２つ以上があっても処理済みと記載をしたいの例です。

Comment: その場合は `df.loc[(df['国'] == query[0]), 'フラグ'] = "処理済み"` とします。

Comment: 早速回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法は私にとって結構難しいので勉強します。

Comment: 下記の方法でもできましたが、全てのD列に処理済みを記載したいですが、`for j in range(len(query) - 1):
  print('  D'+str(row + j), str("処理済み")  )
row += len(query) - 1`を入れてみましたが上手く処理できず`アメリカ　カリフォルニア 処理済み`
までしかフラグ記載されないです。もし分かれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 0):

下記の３点を変更・追加しましたら、実現したい内容処理できました。

①

```
groupbyにsort=Falseを追加して、データをソートさせないようにする。
エクセル順番で行う。
```

②

```
#ループ処理の部分とエクセルへの書き込み処理(行)が合っていないので、
#row = 1を追加

row = 1
```

③

```
 # 処理済みのでデータをD列へ入力
    v_ws['D'+str(row)].value = str("処理済み")
    
    #追加した行とリストのデータと合わせる  
    row += len(query) - 1
```

```
# generate search words 
# sort=False データソートせずにエクセル順番で行う
lst = (
  df.groupby(1, sort=False,as_index=False)[2]
    .agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    .apply(lambda x: [x[1]] + x[2], axis=1)

    .tolist()
)
print(lst)

URL = "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en"

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

#ループ処理の部分とエクセルへの書き込み処理(行)が合っていないので、
#row = 1を追加

row = 1

for i, query in enumerate(lst):
    # Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
    if i > 0:
      driver.execute_script('window.open()')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    driver.get(URL)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # country
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(query[0])

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # 都市1つ以上がある場合
    if len(query) > 1:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
      city2.send_keys(query[1])
      print(' 都市1つ以上')

    # 都市2つ以上がある場合
    if len(query) > 2:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
      city2.send_keys(query[2])
      print(' 都市2つ以上')

    # 都市3つ以上がある場合
    if len(query) > 3:
      city3 = driver.find_element_by_name("noneOfTheseWords")
      city3.send_keys(query[3])
      print(' 都市3つ以上')
  
    print('D'+str(row), str("処理済み")  )
    # 処理済みのでデータをD列へ入力
    v_ws['D'+str(row)].value = str("処理済み")
    
    #追加した行とリストのデータと合わせる  
    row += len(query) - 1

  
# EXCEL保存  
v_wb.save("test2.xlsx")
```